# MySQL Date subtract from Month & Date Format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a silly question that I want to find no of days within curdate() and next 30 days, from MySQL column "increment_date" formatted as DD-MON (10-Nov, 15-Nov etc...)

I tried to get values as 8, 13 from that dates while comparing curdate()

## tbl_officer

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+
| in_num | last_name | increment_date |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
|      1 | AA        | 10-Nov         |
|      2 | BB        | 12-Nov         |
|      3 | CC        | 20-Dec         |
|      4 | DD        | 22-Dec         |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

I used the following code to do that

```
select last_name 
  from tbl_officer
 where increment_date>= DATE(curdate()) 
   and increment_date<= DATE_SUB(DATE(curdate()), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

But the code outs empty result. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What happens when it's late December and your `increment_date` is `10-Jan`. How do you know if that refers to the current year or the next year?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: With `increment_date>= DATE(curdate()) and increment_date<= DATE_SUB(DATE...` you have no dates that can match this - greater than today and less than today minus 31 days - those dates don't/can't exist. Either you can have <= CURDATE() (no need for DATE(CURDATE())) AND >= ... -31 DAY or >= CURDATE() AND <= CURDATE() + 1 MONTH (as in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_to_date()` function with `"%d-%b-%Y"` pattern after combining with the current year(assuming you stay within the current year) :

```
select count(*) as "Number of Days"
  from tbl_officer
 where str_to_date(concat(increment_date,'-',year(curdate())),"%d-%b-%Y")
       between curdate() and curdate() + interval 30 day;

 Number of Days
 --------------
 2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19ea7f9979ba4ff272af3862da002b58)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

> `STR_TO_DATE` function to be used to convert string data in different
>   format into a date value.

Your table data doesn't has year value so we need to append the current year on the fly, for eg:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_officer where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(increment_date, '-2019'), "%d-%b-%Y")
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

So here is how I would complete it:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_officer where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(increment_date, '-', YEAR(NOW())), "%d-%b-%Y") 
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

Comment: Could you post the table/data structure

Comment: Added the table/data structure

Comment: @MCITTrends soo if you dont have year value, if there is lets say 10-OCT will it  mean to 2019 or 2020 ?

Comment: @ Bilal Siddiqui. No it doesn't have definite year value. That is fixed only a date & month.

Comment: @MCITTrends then hopefully my updated answer works for you .

Comment: but those queries return all 4 rows instead of 2. Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=49f4010e10ba5e874009586f480494ff) out @MCITTrends

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited answer to use NOW() in DATE_ADD function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ea210d2388afa8bc88e6c5f8ddca399)):

Create and populate your table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_officer
(
  in_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  increment_date VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_officer VALUES (1, 'AA', '10-Nov'), (2, 'BB', '12-Nov'), (3, 'CC', '20-Dec'),
(4, 'DD', '22-Dec'), (5, 'XX', '15-Nov');  -- XX added for testing
```

Then run this SQL (there are a couple of intermediary steps in the fiddle):

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM tbl_officer
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(increment_date, '-2019'), "%d-%M-%Y") >= CURDATE() 
AND   STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(increment_date, '-2019'), "%d-%M-%Y") <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Result:

```
last_name
       AA
       BB
       XX
```